# How to sum digits from integer in c++?

Tags: c++

I want to sum digits of an integer. If I have 123 I want to sum 1+2+3. I found a program that works well but I don't understand how it works. Can you explain how it works?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
 int n, sum;
 cout << "Enter integer\n";
 cin >> n;
 sum = n/100 + (n/10)%10 + n%10;
 cout << "sum = " << sum << endl;
}
```

How `n/100` generates 1 from 123, `(n/10)%10` 2 from 123 and `n%10` 3 from 123

Comment: Its called de modulo operation (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) Is de remainder of the division of 2 numbers. So 23 % 10 = 3

Comment: As well as @RvdK's comment, also note that divisions with integer arguments return an integer with any fractional part discarded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sum = n/100 + (n/10)%10 + n%10;
```

1) `n/100`
(n=123)
 in this statement 123/100 means ans `is = 1`

2)`(n/10)%10`
here `(123/10)` firstly evaluate and ans `is = 12`, and then `12%10` gets evaluate and ans `is = 2`

3)`n%10` again `123%10` evaluate ans is `3`

then statement becomes

```
sum = 1 + 2 + 3
```

Note: `%` symbol gives remainder

Answer (score 0):

These are very simple maths.

Here, n = 123

```
100 | 123 | 1
      100
   _________
       23
```

Therefore the quotient is 1.

The same way, for 123/10,

```
10 | 123 | 12
     10
___________
      23
      20
___________
       3
```

So, 123/10 = 12. Now for (123/10)%10 = 12%10,

```
10 | 12 | 1
     10
   ______
      2
```

Therefore, (123/10)%10 = 12%10 = 2.

The same way, 123%10 = 3

Therefore, the answer is:  123/100 + (123/10)%10 + 123%10 = 1 + 2 + 3 = 6

(Note: a % b, here b divides a and returns the remainder)